# Making function with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning to write function with the library `data.table`. After experiments, i used `get()` to convert a variable to an object.
Would like to know if there is more ways to realize it?

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(
  V1=rep(letters[1:3],5),
  V2=c(2:16)
)

Test1 <- DT[,.((V2-sd(V2))/(max(V2)-min(V2))), by=.(V1)] # for comparision

Norma <- function(dataset, Vari, group_by){
  dataset[,
          .((get(Vari)-sd(get(Vari)))/(max(get(Vari))-min(get(Vari)))),
          by=.(get(group_by))    
    ]
}


Test2 <- Norma(DT,"V2","V1")
```

it works, Test1 is identical to Test2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `get`, we can specify the columns of interest where the function needs to be applied in `.SDcols` and then loop through the columns.  Here, it is only one column, so we extract that column as a vector using `[[`

```
Norma <- function(dataset, Vari, group_by){
   dataset[,
      .((.SD[[1]]-sd(.SD[[1]]))/(max(.SD[[1]])-min(.SD[[1]]))),
      by= group_by, .SDcols = Vari  
   ]
 }

identical(Norma(DT, "V2", "V1"), Test1)
#[1] TRUE
```