# How to use data.table inside a function call?

Tags: r, data.table

### 1

I want to use `data.table` inside a self-defined fuction, I get errors:

```
> library(data.table)
> DT = data.table(a = c(6,3,1,9,NA), b = 4:8)
> DT
    a b
1:  6 4
2:  3 5
3:  1 6
4:  9 7
5: NA 8
> fillna = function(df,var){
+   col = df[[var]]
+   set(df, i = which(is.na(col)), j = var, value = mean(col, na.rm=T))
+ }
>
> fillna(DT,a)
Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  :
  object 'a' not found
>
```

How to fix it?

### 2

I also tried to use `get()` from this post:

[Making function with data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082887/making-function-with-data-table-in-r)

but it still fails:

```
> fillna = function(df,var){
+   df[is.na(get(var)),var:=mean(df[[var]],na.rm = T)]
+   df
+ }
>
> fillna(DT,a)
Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x) :
  Object 'a' not found. Perhaps you intended a, b
```

Comment: You can use `var = as.character(substitute(var))` if you want to pass column names without quotes.

Comment: Okay, it is really a good idea! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to pass the column name as string

```
fillna = function(df,var){
    col = df[[var]]
    set(df, i = which(is.na(col)), j = var, value = mean(col, na.rm=T))
    return(df)
}

fillna(DT,"a")

#      a b
#1: 6.00 4
#2: 3.00 5
#3: 1.00 6
#4: 9.00 7
#5: 4.75 8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of `deparse(substitute` (similar to @dww's comments) here if the OP want to pass unquoted column name as argument

```
fillna = function(df,var){
    var  <- deparse(substitute(var))
    col <- df[[var]]
    set(df, i = which(is.na(col)), j = var, value = mean(col, na.rm=TRUE))[]

}

fillna(DT, a)
#      a b
#1: 6.00 4
#2: 3.00 5
#3: 1.00 6
#4: 9.00 7
#5: 4.75 8
```

---

Or another option is `match.call`

```
fillna = function(df,var){
    var <- as.character(as.list(match.call())$var)
    col <- df[[var]]
    set(df, i = which(is.na(col)), j = var, value = mean(col, na.rm=TRUE))[]

}

fillna(DT, a)
```

Comment: Your answer is really helpful!